# Performance of INSERT vs INSERT-only clause in INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE with no CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql

This question concerns PostgreSQL 13.0

Is there a performance difference between an INSERT statement vs. an INSERT... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE statement if the CONFLICT is never triggered?

I have a weekly bulk data load task where we COPY vendor data into a staging table, perform various exercises with it, and then merge it into our larger historical tables. When this process was first developing, the data volume was relatively low and the vendor did not always send non-overlapping data sets week by week, so we set up an INSERT... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE statement to handle scenarios where the data in one week overlapped data in the prior week's delivery.

The process has now scaled to include much larger volumes of data and better partitioning by the vendor such that we rarely have any overlap between one week to the next. I'm curious if there's a negative performance impact by putting a larger volume of records through the "upsert" transaction  where the UPDATE is not needed, vs. some process by which I explicitly identify rows to INSERT versus rows to UPDATE and load the data in two separate transactions.

Comment: There has to be some overhead in order for the `ON CONFLICT` to assess the possible conflict depending on the constraints chosen. For your case the only way to know how much and whether it is a problem is run some tests against your data with and without the `ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: As @AdrianKlaver indicates there must be some overhead, but unless the conflict occurs you will (probably) never notice. However, perhaps a more pertinent question is "What is the performance implications of the resulting exception when it does occur vs. the microseconds overhead when it does not . **Complete and correct must always supersede performance** especially then the reduced performance will never be noticed. (stepping down from soapbox)